# Adding a click event to hide a popup

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling

I have a popup with an id of `myPopup`.
`show` is a class that changes the display from none to block.
This is my first time using event handlers and I was looking to get some information on the different types and how to use them.

```
var popup_v = document.getElementById("myPopup");

function popup() {
    popup_v.classList.toggle("show");
}
if(document.getElementById('myPopup').classList.contains("show")) {
    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        popup_v.classList.remove("show");
    });
}
```

Comment: *"This is my first time to use xy - I want some information"* is not a well structured question. You forgot to explain what's your actual issue you're facing. Please [edit], improve your question (you can use literate `?` question marks to focus a reader to a specific question)  - and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think the event only runs if there is a class and there is one if statement, the if statement is run only once so... It won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var popup_v = document.getElementById("myPopup");

function popup() {
    popup_v.classList.toggle("show");
}
if(document.getElementById('myPopup').classList.contains("show")) {
    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        popup_v.classList.remove("show");
    });
```

So first of all your if statement will only run once and since the class is only toggled during the function, then the if statement will never be run and so the event won't actually happen.
To fix this maybe try this approach:

```
var popup_v = document.getElementById("myPopup");

var trueorfalse = false;

function popup() {
    if (trueorfalse === false) }
     trueorfalse = true; // popup is there
     popup_v.classList.toggle("show");
    } else {
     popup_v.classList.remove("show");
    }
}
if(document.getElementById('myPopup').classList.contains("show")) {
    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        popup_v.classList.remove("show");
    });
```

OR

```
var popup_v = document.getElementById("myPopup");

function popup() {
    popup_v.classList.toggle("show");
}
var trueorfalse = false;
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
 if (trueorfalse === false) }
  trueorfalse = true; // popup is there
  popup_v.classList.toggle("show");
 } else {
  popup_v.classList.remove("show");
 }
}
};
```

I did it these ways because the event listener just checks if the event is happening for how long the application (site) is run.

So you can just check if the class is there or not and then decide depending on that.

Tell me if anything is wrong.

Comment: Thank You for reminding me that the click needs to be looped or called with the function. The code for the first one has a few code errors so It was hard to understand what braces went together. I tried putting in the second piece of code and did not show the popup at all. I didn't really find the error but thanks for the information. I feel like I have a better approch on it now

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a need to add the if condition specifically to check if it contains class and it it has remove it.

the toggle method should do both for you, i.e.
on toggle add show class,
on toggle again if show class is present remove it

check this example for reference - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_class

Comment: *"for a really bad reference"*. w3schools is the worst resource (still in 2021) to point new users to learn from. In that specific example - disseminating click events inside the HTML markup is considered from ages a really bat thing to do. JS should be in one place only, and that's your script tag / file.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan well it's just an example link not a resource link, it simply has a function which toggle's between class and would be helpful to understand how it works

Comment: Also, if w3schools website goes down one day or the link changes - your question would be pretty much useless. If provides no legitimate resource to an authoritative resource and shows no code samples.

Comment: Also, it's pretty much obvious OP knows really well about [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)